# How to let a Select on a navigationproperty return a array in Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I have the following query which compiles fine

```
query.Select(p => new DataObject() {
    Id = p.Id,
    TaskIds = p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskId).ToArray()
});
```

but ends in a runtime exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid[]
>   ToArrayGuid'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is the DataObject Class

```
public class DataObject {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public Guid[] TaskIds { get; set; }
}
```

**My Question is: How can I return a `Guid[]` by selecting from a navigationproperty of a entity**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to postpone the creation of the array until after the translation to SQL, to do it on the in-memory side.

```
query.Select(p => new {
    Id = p.Id,
    TaskIds = p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskId)
})
.AsEnumerable()  // <-- SQL translation up to here. Anything after is done in-memory
.Select(p => new DataObject() {
    Id = p.Id,
    TaskIds = TaskIds.ToArray()
})
```

Comment: Is your way better then `p.Tasks.ToList().Select(t => t.TaskId).ToArray()` expect the fact that I can reduce the amount of data using a select?

Comment: @JRR that's enough of a reason to do it that way. The less data you can return from your query, the less resource intensive your application will be.

Comment: @BrianBall I am with you. I just want to understand it, that's why I asked if there is another reason.

Comment: You're correct, that's really the only difference. Obviously if you can reduce the rows being returned, that would be even better (just put your filter before the `AsEnumerable()` call).

Answer (score 1):

It's because EF will always try to convert your linq query into tsql operation. 
You should  bring it in memory like this :

```
 p.Tasks.ToList().Select(t => t.TaskId).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to choose Maartens as correct because it is a bit more optimized and in addition he was the first who answered. But you got my +1